# A web browser localy encrypted by default

Tags: encryption, web-browser, public-key-infrastructure

Some years ago, I've found a web browser which I can't remember the name. It had pretty impressive security standards. For example:

1. Symmetric encryption key (password) is mandatory for saving browsing session/history/browser configurations. Otherwise none of that data is kept.
2. Private-public key pair generation for direct user interaction, asking passwords for the private key (Unfortunately, I don't remember the purpose. Probably signing and verifying emails.)

I thought it would be easy to find it again, or at least some equivalent browser, but after some days searching, nothing!

The nearest I could find was Gnome Web with Seahorse, but from what I see, I doubt it serves the same purpose (specially the first one):

https://help.gnome.org/users/seahorse-plugins/stable/web-browser.html.en

Does anybody knows something like that?

Comment: 1) Product recommendations are off-topic on Security SE, exactly because of the reason like your case. What may look good today can disappear tomorrow. Where as Security SE has a goal to provide answers that are valid for a long time. 2) To the question about encryption: See the answer.

Comment: it defies me why browsers don't encrypt more of their backend as a matter of course- the password database is encrypted, not to mention high 90-somethn% of the traffic on the wire - imho. it's perfectly reasonable to expect that local storage, cache, history, bookmarks, telemetry, config. and plugins, etal. should also be secured with modern cryptography out of the box .. encrypting the drive that the profile lives on is essential - imho. this becomes necessary because the sensitive profile itself is otherwise unprotected

Comment: @mentallurg I see. The purpose of my question is not necessarily searching for a product/tool, but searching for a service (in this case, the items above) and a product or configuration able to provide this service.

Comment: @brynk Why should they? Use FDE if that's a relevant threat vector.

Comment: @vidarlo is fde even a solution? the processing environment and data can be highly sensitive, and not all users are capable or confident to secure their own storage (with either profile or full-disc encryption, or even just semantically with acls) .. meanwhile, not all exploits are equal - the filesystem may be within reach of the browser process eg. via `file://` while unencrypted data and keys in ram are still partially/ completely out of reach .. finally, fde alone can't ensure the integrity of extensions, whereas app-logic might be better able to facilitate this

Answer (score 0):

[All](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/generateKey#browser_compatibility) modern major browsers support [Web Crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API). In particular, they provide the possibility to [generate keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/generateKey) for asymmetric encryption.

Encryption is very complex subject to implement it properly. [Here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=433875) is the reason why FireFox has refused to implement it. Depending on the system you have, you can encrypt the full disk (BitLocker on WIndows, LUKS on Linux, FileVault on Mac), or encrypt your home directory, or use tools that create virtual encrypted disks (VeryCrypt or similar). Even this work only under certain conditions. For instance, if you don't fully control the computer, then the administrator can create a memory dump of your browser process or look at swap and retrieve passwords in plain form. Then the administrator can decrypt any data you have encrypted.